# How do I fix a "IntegrationError: No such sku: "prod_....." error when using Gatsby and Stripe

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, gatsby

I'm creating a test site using Gatsby and Stripe.

At the moment, I have 2 products set up in my Stripe account; I can render these successfully in a Gatsby site, created using the standard starter template.

In my gatsby-config.js file, I have this for the Stripe setup:

```
      resolve: `gatsby-source-stripe`,
      options: {
        objects: ["Product", "Price"],
        secretKey: process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY,
        downloadFiles: true,
      },
```

The query and rendering code I'm using is this:

```
const Skus = () => {
  return (
    <StaticQuery
      query={graphql`
        query SkusForProduct {
          skus: allStripePrice {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                currency
                unit_amount
                unit_amount_decimal
                product {
                  images
                  unit_label
                  description
                  name
                  id
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `}
      render={({ skus }) => (
        <div style={containerStyles}>
          {skus.edges.map(({ node: sku }) => (
            <SkuCard key={sku.product.id} sku={sku} stripePromise={stripePromise} />
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    />
  )
}
```

I have a separate component (SkuCard), which is used to render the details of each product - the core code looks like this:

```
const formatPrice = (amount, currency) => {
  let price = (amount / 100).toFixed(2)
  let numberFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat(["en-US"], {
    style: "currency",
    currency: currency,
    currencyDisplay: "symbol",
  })
  return numberFormat.format(price)
}

const SkuCard = ({ sku, stripePromise }) => {

  const redirectToCheckout = async (event, sku, quantity = 1) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const stripe = await stripePromise
    const { error } = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      items: [{ sku, quantity }],
      successUrl: `${window.location.origin}/page-2/`,
      cancelUrl: `${window.location.origin}/advanced`,
    })
    if (error) {
      console.warn("Error:", error)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div style={cardStyles}>
      <h4>{sku.product.name}</h4>
      <img src={sku.product.images} alt={sku.product.name} />
      <p>Price: {formatPrice(sku.unit_amount, sku.currency)}</p>
      <p>ID: {sku.product.id}</p>
      <button
        style={buttonStyles}
        onClick={event => redirectToCheckout(event, sku.product.id)}
      >
        BUY ME
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SkuCard
```

**My Issue**:
Each time I click on the Buy Me button, I'm getting this error in console log:

[image]

**The steps I've taken:**

- Confirmed that the ID against the "No such sku" error is indeed one of my test products;
- Tried altering the GraphQL query to see if I'm picking up the wrong ID entry - I have tried ones under `sku.id` and `sku.product.id` (using the GraphiQL browser), but neither work;
- Added a tag to the products displayed to confirm what I believe to be the correct product ID (same as the one shown in the screenshot), can be rendered on screen in the product details - this is displayed without issue;
- Scoured the internet to see if anyone else has done similar examples - nothing found;
- Used the example code from the main Gatsby site to confirm that I can at least put a single "hard-coded" product through the checkout process - that works. (My chosen method though is to render products dynamically, not as hard-coded items on the page)
- Checked the Stackoverflow site: questions have been asked about Stripe & Gatsby, but not found anything yet that is close to this issue.

I'm trying to figure out what is causing this error - can anyone help please?

Comment: A Product (prod_****) is not a SKU, which is why you're seeing that error. See https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migrating-prices for a migration guide that covers what you appear to be trying to do.

Comment: That doc was a great help - with a little more work and alteration to the ```items``` object, I got it working! For anyone in a similar problem, the items object had to be changed to this:
```
      lineItems: [{
        price: sku,
        quantity: quantity,
      }],
      mode: 'payment',
```
I also had to adjust the GraphQL query property being pulled in - otherwise all good.

Thanks for your help taintedzodiac!